# Curl Error with SSL/TLS Certificate Revocation Check on Windows Server 2022 via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl, curl

I've been developing a program on Windows Server 2022 that uses Curl within PowerShell to upload files. Two weeks ago, I successfully executed the Curl command from within PowerShell. However, starting from yesterday, I've been encountering an error.

Regarding my network setup: The Windows Server executing the script isn't directly connected to the internet. It communicates with servers on the internet via a Forward Proxy.

I've set up the proxy settings within PowerShell and then executed curl. When doing so, I get the following error:

> curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown
> error (0x80092013)

From the error message, I inferred that it might be failing to verify the revocation of the SSL/TLS certificate being used. When I tried executing with the --ssl-no-revoke option, it worked without any issues.

I've managed to identify the probable cause, but I'm unsure how to proceed to correctly handle the certificate's revocation check.

If anyone knows how to address this, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance.

Comment: You are probably using OAUTH2 two step authentication. You probably got a valid token/cookie from another application and your PS code then worked because token was stored as a cookie.  When token expired the application started to fail.